# Python regex only working for substring matches but not the whole string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove all bracketed and parenthetical text. I am using the regex

`re.sub(r'\(.*\) | \[.*\]', '', text)`

This works for things like:

```
import re
text = 'the (quick) brown fox jumps over the [lazy] dog'
print re.sub(r'\(.*\) | \[.*\]', '', text)

> the brown fox jumps over the dog

text = '(the quick) brown fox jumps over the [lazy] dog'
print re.sub(r'\(.*\) | \[.*\]', '', text)

> brown fox jumps over the dog
```

But it fails when the entire string matches the regex

```
text = '[the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog]'
print re.sub(r'\(.*\) | \[.*\]', '', text)

> [the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog]

> # This should be '' (the empty string) #
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I would be careful with the greedy matching though. If you have a random ") " in your text that may just be a standalone symbol, then this regex will get rid of everything in between. For ex. `"This is a (small) sample text with a ) symbol"` would turn into `"This is a symbol"`. Maybe use the reluctant match? (see my answer edit)

Comment: @gowrath That's an important note. In my case, I am confident because I formatted the data, but in the general case it's something that must be handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have extra space over the regex, just need to remove the space before and after `|`

```
re.sub(r'\(.*\)|\[.*\]', '', text)
```

or make them an optional match to match your existing output

```
re.sub(r'\(.*\)\s?|\s?\[.*\]', '', text)
```

Comment: Ah damn. Of course. So much for Python emphasizing use of whitespace ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra space that it is trying to match :)

Try:

```
re.sub(r'\(.*\)|\[.*\]', '', text)
```

A good place to test when regex does weird stuff like this is [here](http://regexr.com). It's a nice interactive way to see what's going wrong. For ex. in your case, it didn't match "(pace)" but matched "(pace) " as soon as I put a space after it.

**Note:**

As I mentioned in the comment, be aware that the greedy match might do unexpected things if you have a random ")" in your text that may just be a standalone symbol. Consider the reluctant matching instead:

```
re.sub(r'\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]', '', text)
```

which would turn:

```
This is a (small) sample text with a ) symbol" ===> "This is a sample text with a ) symbol"
```

whereas yours currently would give:

```
This is a (small) sample text with a ) symbol" ===> "This is a symbol"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = '''[the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog]
the (quick) brown fox jumps over the [lazy] dog
(the quick) brown fox jumps over the [lazy] dog'''
print (re.sub(r'[(\[].+?[)\]]', '', text))
```

out:

```
the  brown fox jumps over the  dog
 brown fox jumps over the  dog
```

Comment: This will match unbalanced parens and turn something like: `"This is a [ symbol and this is a ) symbol"` into `"This is a symbol".`